# Move messages from Junk to Inbox automatically

Tags: icloud, email

I've read plenty of people complaining about iCloud Mail's junk mail handling, with too many false positives. The only answers I've seen are "You can't turn it off" and "You have to use icloud.com on a desktop to mark as not junk, and that might work".

icloud.com mail is awful, and I'll also go entire days without using my home desktop - and even if I do this, the first message from a new contact might end up in junk and get ignored - so I'm looking for an automated way of checking my junk folder without having to think about it or check manually.

Ideally, some kind of rule to either stop messages from going in, or find any messages and move them back. Is there an existing IFTTT rule, iPhone Shortcut, Apple Script, anything like that, which might do this on a regular basis?

This problem is on the iCloud server side, not junk mail handling in the Mac Mail app.

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding, mail rules in your local mail client would be your best bet, whichever client that may be. Only one of your clients has to enforce the rule for it to propagate to the rest of your mail clients.

For example in Apple Mail on MacOS:

[image: Mail rules on MacOS]

Comment: I’m using the Apple Mail client on Mac, and I actually have that exact rule, which doesn’t fire. My guess is that it hits for messages that the client considers junk rather than messages that the server has already put into the junk folder. I do have the local junk setting disabled, so I don’t think the rule does anything at all.

Comment: I think Apple Mail rules just run on the Inbox - so if they are in Junk or Spam it is too late, (I now use a paid for mail supplier after getting too much bounceback spam)